# add_rewrite_rule and template redirect not working

Tags: posts, customization, url-rewriting, templates, redirect

I have the following pairs:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^questions/ask/?','index.php?pagename=ask','top');
if(is_page('ask')){
        $tname = 'add-question.php';
        if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname)){
            $returntemplate = TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname;
        }else{
            $returntemplate = $plugindir.'/default-template/'.$tname;
        }
        ahaali_do_theme_redirect($returntemplate);
```

and:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^questions/ed/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=ed&id=$matches[1]','top');
if(is_page('ed')){
            $tname = 'edit-question.php';
            if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname)){
                $returntemplate = TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname;
            }else{
                $returntemplate = $plugindir.'/default-template/'.$tname;
            }
            ahaali_do_theme_redirect($returntemplate);
        }
```

Now what happens is the following:
The first rule and template redirect works while the second one does not. I have added in the header of my theme

```
print_r($wp->query_vars);
```

the result is:

```
Array ( [pagename] => ed [id] => 10 )
```

So the rule itself works but the template redirect does not. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, if a page is a child of another page, the pagename value is the full parent / child path. In your examples it would be `pagename=questions/ask` and `pagename=questions/ed`, though you say the first rule works, which is puzzling.

also, side note - there's a [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) function that will correctly handle parent / child themes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need add your own query_var to get work

```
// Add query_var
function add_question_var($question_vars) {
    $question_vars[] = 'ed';    
    return $question_vars;
}
//add a rewrite rule
function do_rewrite_question() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_rule('question/ask/?$', 'index.php?pagename=ask','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('question/ed/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=question&ed=$matches[1]','top');    
}
function template_redirect_file()
{
    global $wp_query;
    if ( get_query_var('pagename')=='ask')
    {
    // Do your stuff
    }
    if ( $wp_query->get('ed'))
    {
    // Do your stuff
    }   

}
// redirect_canonical
function noredir($redirect_url)
{
    $vars = array (
    'ed' => get_query_var('ed'),    
    );
    if (!empty($vars))
    return false;
}


add_filter('query_vars', 'add_question_var');
add_action('init', 'do_rewrite_question');
add_action('template_redirect', 'template_redirect_file');
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'noredir');
```

then you should **update the permalink** via wp-admin/options-permalink.php
to test the rewrite work, add this code in **add-question.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['pagename'])) {
    echo urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['pagename']);
}
?>
```

and in **edit-question.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['ed'])) {
    echo urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['ed']);
}
?>
```